# access child namespace in parent constructor

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I have child class in different namespace than it's parent abstract class
in child class construct method looks like this:

```
namespace someNameSpace;

class childClass extends \parentClass

    function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
```

in parent class constructor I should call another class method in child namespace.
Something like this:

```
abstract class parentClass

function __construct()
{
    somenameSpace\anotherChildClass::method();
}
```

the problem: I can't just write **somenameSpace\anotherChildClass** because I have many child classes each in different namespace, and namespace should be dynamic.

If I write just **anotherChildClass::method();**
I got class not found error because it executed in parent namespace. How could I solve this?

Comment: Usually, without Namespaces, how do you refer to a childClass method in parent Class? ...

Comment: Without namespaces I just call $this->method
but I don't need child method, I need different class in same namespaces than child

Comment: In Parent Class? And if the Parent Class is directly instantiated? How can your call work? You don't have to call _eventually_ child methods in parent Class. Parent Class have to be standalone. BTW, you don't have to add Namespaces because Child Class inherit all parent methods and inside the class there are not Namespaces.

Comment: Besides, `$this` and `self::` are no references to child class, but to class itself.

Comment: Parent class is abstract class and can't be directly instantiated.

Comment: Found temp. solution: using get_class($this) in parent constructor I can get child classname with namespace. Than I can parse string to extract child namespace from it. Maybe there is easier solution?

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that. Call it in standard way: `$this->method();`. Side note: is **very bad practice** call in abstract class a not-defined method: add at least `abstract function method();` inside class.

Comment: Try overlooking Namespaces, it will works! Namespaces are outside the class.

Comment: $this->method will work for method in child class, but I need only child namespace and another class method is this namespace.
e.g childClassSibling->someMethod();

Comment: OK, I understand. Do you have solved the problem, anyway, right?

Comment: Yes, I found solutions. I still have feeling that it can be done easier, by my solution works now.